# Retrieving data from firebase Realtime Datbase with SwiftUI Xcode 11

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, xcode11

For a few days I have been trying to read my data from firebase without success.
Indeed it is a set of tables also containing tables.

This function is to retrieve the subjects and at the same time the paragraphs

```
func getSubjects() {
    let subjectRef = database.child("subjects")
    subjectRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            print(snapshot)
             if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let subject = Subject(snapshot.value)
            //subjectList.append(subject)
           // print("Data : \(subject)")
                
        }
    })
}
```

[This is the firebase screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLCXV.png)

[Console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWo7G.png)

On Android I didn't have this problem, but since I'm new to iOS, I'm having a hard time coping.
Any help will be welcome. Thank you

Comment: So a subject is marked as a number in your database?

Comment: Yes like tables from 0 to 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you are observing the database for constant changes and it will only run when a child/value has been added into the place you're currently checking, for this you may only want to retrieve a value once, and every time that view is loaded then it will fetch from the database again. It's a lot more efficient and less costly. You may want something like this:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("subjects").child("0").child("paragraphs").child("0").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let location = value["location"] as? NSDictionary
        let title= value?["title"] as? String ?? ""
        let text = value?["text"] as? String ?? ""
        let latitude = location?["latitude"] as? String ?? ""
        let longitude = location?["longitude "] as? String ?? ""
    }) { (error) in
     print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

You think each child with nodes inside it as an array, or a json object. You can cast them into an `NSDictionary` and use that cast to access values inside them if they're nested.

If they're not nested and in the same level as the place you're watching in the database ref, like for instance, above we are looking in the subjects > 0 > paragraphs > 0 node within the database. Title is a value inside that node and not a child so we can simply get the value of title from the database through the data snapshot given back.

I recommend reading the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start), they're very good and easy to understand when working with different OS/languages.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the quick response. I want to get all subject in order the put them in a tableView and after do the same for paragraphs. Should I do it this way for all sujects and paragraphs??  And I aslo don't know how to log data in xcode console?

Comment: Yeh so that’s they way you could do it, obviously you change it to the layout of your database as I do not know they whole layout. But that’s a good and efficient way of retrieving data every time your view loads. To get every subject in order, since they’re numbered from 0, then you cans just use a for loop and use the index to point to the right places in the database. To see stuff in the console you just simply do a print(whatever here, like a variable to see the data)

Comment: That's what i was trying to do with the for section but i couldn't know if that works because the console shows something very wired

Comment: Well what does it show? Send me the output? I can’t help if I don’t know

Comment: I added the screenshot to the post cf console screen

Comment: All of that is just normal logs from firebase, you can safely ignore them. Try my code and print out your variables.

Comment: I use your code and try to print the title and the text but nothing is shown

Comment: Well make sure the db reference is correct for your database structure.

Comment: I checked all the references and that's correct. I don't know why it's not working

Comment: Hi Nathan your solution is working now thank you. But only subjects are retrieved correctly not sub collection. By sub collections i mean paragraphs and locations. Any idea for how to get them ??

Comment: Hi, if it worked then please mark it as the answer for future users with a similar question to yours. In regards to that question, it would depend on your database structure. As long as the code above points to a valid point in your database. E.g. Subjects > 0 points to the same place in your database.

Comment: It point to a valid point but i don't know why but i can't access to sub objects. The database structure is in the question. Help please

Comment: Let's continue this in a discussion and I'll try and help.... send me an updated screenshot of your database

Comment: Where do I send it?

Comment: Now I am retrieving all my data but all paragraphs are in last subject I mean every subject have his own list of paragraphs but it seems like paragraphs are being iterated too. How to avoid nested data from iterating ?